# Where to declare a SET in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have been attempting to figure out where I can SET a variable in an SQLQuery. I have 2 different select statements that will have a different WHERE clause depending on the answer to an IF statement, but I would like to only have to run the query to make SET this variable once, and since I am already running the code to find this particular table, I'd like to do it in the first SELECT statement.

The variable I am trying to SET is called regType

```
SELECT S.subID, C.cKey
FROM Comp AS C
JOIN JData AS J ON J.pKey = C.primary
JOIN Sub AS S ON  J.fKey = S.pKey
WHERE ( //This is where I need the variable// )
```

I want to create a variable because I have a second SELECT that uses the same WHERE clause with the same conditions on it.

Where in this can I SET a variable within the SELECT statement so that I can use it in my WHERE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to "set" a variable in a where clause - maybe you mean in the SELECT?

```
SELECT 
    S.subID, 
    C.cKey,
    @regType = ???
FROM Comp AS C
JOIN JData AS J ON J.pKey = C.primary
JOIN Sub AS S ON  J.fKey = S.pKey
WHERE ( ... )
```

Note that the variable will not be accessible in your `WHERE` clause of that query since the `WHERE` clause is evaluated *before* the `SELECT`.  You can either repeat the expression that you're using in the `SET` or set the variable *before* you execute the query.

Comment: So I will have to have a separate `SELECT` statement to populate my regType then if I plan to use it in the block above?

Comment: @Either than or repeat the expression that you use in the `SET`, yes.  You could do that expression in a subquery, but you can't set the variable in the `WHERE`.